# IgonreFilter in Dynamic Query

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I used Dynamic [Library](https://dynamic-linq.net/) in order to generate Lambda Expression that can be executed and return a content based on dynamic query prams,
my problem is with the context filter (using **HasQueryFilter** statement) that I need to ignore it before execute the query
I tried to use IgnoreQueryFilters, but isn't working with the IQueryable

```
  IQueryable<object> EQueryableItems = (IQueryable<object>)typeof(ApplicationDbContext).GetProperty("Users-Table").GetValue(_appDbContext, null)

  IQueryable<object>  QueryResult = (IQueryable<object>) EQueryableItems.Where("Id > 1500");
```

EQueryableItems will contain data based on the context query, I need to get all data not just the result of the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core specific queryable extension methods are available for `IQueryable<object>`, hence it can be used with the provided code:

```
IQueryable<object> EQueryableItems = ...;
EQueryableItems = EQueryableItems.IgnoreQueryFilters(); // <-- defined and works
```

However, if you want to work with non generic `IQueryable` interface, you can create and use a custom extension method similar to

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class CustomQueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable IgnoreQueryFilters(this IQueryable source) =>
            source.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(
                typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions),
                nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IgnoreQueryFilters),
                new[] { source.ElementType },
                source.Expression));
    }
}
```

which would enable usage of

```
IQueryable EQueryableItems = ...;
EQueryableItems = EQueryableItems.IgnoreQueryFilters(); // <-- custom defined and works
```

You can add similar custom extensions methods for other EF Core specific `IQueryable<T>` extension methods like `AsNoTracking()`, `AsTracking()`, `AsSplitQuery()` etc. if needed, using the same pattern as the above implementation.

Comment: thank you for your help,
as I mentioned in my post, I tried to use IgnoreQueryFilters
It throws an exception on the "Where" statement line,
actually it return the flowing error : 
No property or filed "id" exists in type object

Comment: Then changing the type to `IQueryable` and using the custom extension method should work, since it is keeping the original element type, rather than `object` as with `IQueryable<object>`,

Comment: Dear Ivan I tried both ways, unfortunately I've got same error
{"No property or field 'id' exists in type 'Object'"}

Comment: It works for me. According to the error message, somewhere before `Where` you are converting the query to `IQueryable<object>` which then is causing `Where` to fail. Following is my test which works (I'm using [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq) and latest EF Core 5 if that matters):  `var query = ((IQueryable)typeof(ApplicationDbContext).GetProperty("Users-Table").GetValue(_appDbContext, null)).IgnoreQueryFilters().Where("Id > 1500");`